# Trigger a click event with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an click function that I want to trigger outside of the function with parameters.

```
<div id="menubar">
    <a id="menu_file_open">File Open</a>
    <a id="menu_file_save">Save File</a>
</div>


$("#menubar a").click(function(event){

    var menu_item = $(this).attr('id');
    var $context = $(this);

    switch(menu_item){

        case 'menu_file_open':
             //Do menu file open dialog
        break;

        case 'menu_file_save': break;

    }

});

$('#menubar a').trigger('click'); //not working (ID,context not defined);
```

How would I pass in the ID and the context of the div as it was actually clicked.

Comment: What you have should work.. provided the link has an ID and the context should be link element. Just a tip: You can just do `$('#menubar a').click()` instead of `.trigger`

Comment: Also, you may want to filter that down to a specific anchor element rather than triggering the click handler on all of them at once, depending on what you are trying to do of course.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/fbkxk/. Is jQuery loaded properly?

Comment: I have more then one item so thanks so I just need to say: $('#menubar a#ID_HERE').trigger('click'); and it works. Thanks you Kevin B.

Comment: check this it works for more than one elements too http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/gPvfc/1/ . Though I am not sure if you want to trigger click for all of them at once,

Comment: `$("#ID_HERE")` is sufficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <a id="click_me" href="#">Click me</a>
    <a id="dont_click" href="#">Don't click</a>
</div>

$("#menubar a").click(function(event){
    var menu_item = $(this).attr('id');
    var $context = $(this);

    //....
});

$('#menubar a#click_me').click();​ // or $('#menubar a#dont_click').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Calling `click()` is just a short cut for calling `trigger('click')`

Comment: You're Right! I always used `click()` :p.
I'll update my post according to your hint!

Comment: @CezarisLT: Are u still having the `context not defined` problem? Because this could mean likely that you've problems with the `JQuery` library.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass and retrieve [arbitrary data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/) to a jQuery event handler, like so:

```
$(selector).click({ dataItem1: 'value1', dataItem2: 'value2' }, function(e) {
    var val1 = e.data.dataItem1,
        val2 = e.data.dataItem2;
});
```

However, because your code is [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/fbkxk), I suspect that there may be another problem, like the jQuery library isn't loaded or there is an error else where in your scripts.